# How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: updates, repository

I'm new to ubuntu...
when I type `sudo apt-get update` command, I get those. Help!

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 
'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the component 
'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as 
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the 
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 
 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the component 
 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_US' as           
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the      
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as      
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the 
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-all.yml' as 
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the 
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?) 
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as 
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the 
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as 
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the 
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as 
 repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the 
 component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 
 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the component 
 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-all' as repository 
 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't have the component 
 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added some items to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or added files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which refer to Debian repositories. While Ubuntu uses the "deb" package format, originating on Debian, **Ubuntu is not Debian**. You should not use Debian repositories on Ubuntu.

You should remove or adjust the lines you added to those files, which refer to `deb.debian.org`. If you keep them, and somehow manage to install packages from there, you almost certainly will break your install of Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same warning since not long. I could not find `deb.debian.org` whether in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.